# printing out a list of orders from a form using JS

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, textarea

I've been searching all over and can't seem to find an answer to my simple question.  Basically I have created this form and a `textarea` below, I want to have my orders(you can make multiple orders using the same form) show up in the `textarea` below with the order number beside it.

I can't figure out how to do it. My problem is that I just keep over riding the first post, and I cant get my number to increment.  Any help would be great!

Here is my form...

```
<div id="wrapper">
<h2>EMARKS REQUEST FORM</h2>
<table border="1">
<form id="requestForm">
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="inputText" id="id"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Course Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="inputText" id="courseNum" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="inputText" id="des" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Distance Education</td>
    <td id="checkBox"><input type="checkbox" id="distance"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Additional Marks</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="inputText" id="marks" /></td>
</tr>
</table> <br/>
Number of Courses <input type="text" value="0" /> Total Cost <input type="text" value="0" id="totalCost" /> <br/> <br/>
<h2 style="display:inline">Reasons:</h2>
<input type="radio" value="Doctor Note" />Doctor Note <input type="radio" value="Lack of Work" />Lack of Work <input type="radio" value="Some Compassion" />Some Compassion <br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Go for It" onclick="getPrice()" /> <input type="button" value="Clear and Reset" />
<select>
    <option value="First Time User">First Time User</option>
    <option value="Frequent Flier">Frequent Flier</option>
    <option value="Buying a Degree">Buying a Degree</option>
</select>
<h2>Summary of Your Request(s)</h2>
<textarea rows="10" cols="63" id="summary">
test
</textarea> <br/>
<h2>Danger Range</h2>
<textarea rows="10" cols="63">
test
</textarea> 
</form>
</div>
```

And my Javascript

```
var itemNum = 0;
itemNum++;
var textBoxes = itemNum + " " + document.getElementById("id").value + " " + document.getElementById("courseNum").value + " " + document.getElementById("des").value + " " + document.getElementById("marks").value +" " + totalCost.value;
                var summaryInfo = textBoxes;
            summary.text = summaryInfo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use += to APPEND a string to an existing string.

```
summary.value += summaryInfo
```

Also, you are initializing itemNum to 0, then incrementing it by 1, EVERY time you execute.  You need to initialize it ONCE, then increment it EVERY time, to get the effect you want.

```
var itemNum = 0;

function MyButtonClickHandler()
{
  itemNum++;
  var textBoxes = itemNum + " " + document.getElementById("id").value + " " +   document.getElementById("courseNum").value + " " + document.getElementById("des").value + " " + document.getElementById("marks").value +" " + totalCost.value;
                var summaryInfo = textBoxes;
  summary.value += summaryInfo;
}
```

Comment: Hey Jason! Your "+=" worked great, thanks so much! How exactly would I initialize itemNum? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem’s here:

```
summary.text = summaryInfo;
```

The property is `value`, not `text`.

Comment: I changed it to value and it is still not "adding" the next order, just replacing it.

Comment: @user1876246: Use `+=` then?

Answer (score 0):

Here three things, you have problem:-

1. `form` tag is not opened/closed on the correct place
2. `summary` variable is not declared.
3. As **minitech** said, there is no property called `text`. It is `value`.

   - Do this way

     ```
      document.getElementById("summary").value = textBoxes;
     ```

Answer (score 0):

```
If(itemnum==""){
Itemnum=1;
}
Else
{
Itemnum=Itemnum+1;
}
```

Check the syntax please